# Записать данные из файла в структуру

Tags: c++

Нужно записать данные из файла ( текстового ) в структуру: Фамилия Имя Отчество Группа( цифры ) Название ВУЗа. И затем сделать вывод студентов ( фамилий ), которые учатся в одном и том же заданном учреждении и группе. Решил сделать разделитель чтобы было проще, за него принял (;) . Постоянно вылезают ошибки, то одна её исправлю, тогда другая. Последняя ошибка: string subscrtipt out of range. Помогите скорректировать мой код, изменить в нем что-то или вообще переписать ( если вам не лень и ваше решение лучше ( в любом случае будет лучше ) ) чтобы он заработал.

Примерное содержимое файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде есть проверки которые я добавлял и если что-то не понятно спрашивайте.
Вот сотворенное мною чудовище:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    struct Student {
        string name;
        string fam;
        string ot4;
        int group;
        string inst;
    };

    string str;
    string s;
    string a;
    int j = 0;
    int n;
    int N=0;
    int sum = 0;
    ifstream in ("D://file.txt");
    getline(in, s, '\0');
    cout << s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == ';') {
            N++;
        }
    }
    N = N / 5;
    Student* mas = new Student[N];
    cout << s << endl;
    asdfgh:
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == ';') {
            if (N == 1) mas[j].fam = a; cout << mas[j].fam << endl;
            if (N == 2) mas[j].name = a;
            if (N == 3) mas[j].ot4 = a;
            if (N == 4) { 
                mas[j].group = stoi(a); }
            if (N == 5) {

                N = 0;
                mas[j].inst = a;
                j++; 
            }
            N++;
            a = "";
            goto asdfgh;
        }
        a[i] = s[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        cout << mas[i].fam << endl;
        cout << mas[i].name << endl;
        cout << mas[i].ot4 << endl;
        cout << mas[i].group << endl;
        cout << mas[i].inst << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

UPDATE. 
Есть еще такой код, но он тоже не работает:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{

    string fame;
    string name;
    string surname;
    int group;
    string inst;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ifstream in("D://file.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while (in.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')) // подсчет количества строк для динамичского массива структур
    {
        if (!in.eof()) 
            count++;
    }
    Student* mas = new Student[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {  // тут должна быть запись из файла в элементы структуры
        if (in) {
            in >> mas[i].fame >> mas[i].name >> mas[i].surname >> mas[i].group >> mas[i].inst;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // вывод элементов
        cout << mas[i].fame << endl << mas[i].name << endl << mas[i].surname << endl  << mas[i].group << endl << mas[i].inst << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

UPDATE.

Comment: Как я понял, разделитель заказываете вы. Так? Тогда - у вас везде во всех полях пробелы недопустимы? Или могут быть? Если недопустимы - то я бы выбрал как разделитель пробел и все эти мучения сразу стали бы ни к чему - можно было бы просто читать `file >> field`. Если же `;` принципиально - взгляните на функцию `strtok`.

Comment: @Harry, нет, можно и пробелы, на что фантазии так сказать хватит. У меня есть еще такой код, но он почему-то не работает:

`in >> mas[i].fame >> mas[i].name >> mas[i].surname >> mas[i].group >> mas[i].inst;`

Comment: Ну, может, потому что `"D://file.txt"` удвоение *прямых* слешей не нужно. Это тут - `"D:\\file.txt"` - они нужны... Вы же не проверяете, открыт файл или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, вот решение всем спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    string strf,vibor2;
    int vibor1;
    struct Student
    {

        string fame;
        string name;
        string surname;
        int group;
        string inst;
    };
    string stra;
    ifstream in ("D://file.txt");
    int count = 0;
    getline(in, stra, '\0');
    in.seekg(0);
    while (getline(in, strf))
    {
        y++;
    }
    stringstream ff;
    ff.str(stra);
    Student* mas = new Student[y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        ff >> mas[i].fame >> mas[i].name >> mas[i].surname >> mas[i].group >> mas[i].inst;
    }
    cout << "Выберите ВУЗ: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (mas[i].inst == mas[j].inst) break;
        }
        if (j == i) cout << mas[i].inst << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cin >> vibor2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Выберите группу: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (mas[i].group == mas[j].group) break;
        }
        if (j == i) cout << mas[i].group << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cin >> vibor1;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) 
    {
        if (mas[i].group == vibor1)
        {

            if (mas[i].inst == vibor2)
            {

                cout << mas[i].fame << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }


}
```